# input element inside forgein object of jointjs taking user input

Tags: svg, jointjs

i am adding the forgein object on the click event of the jointjs element via ports
i have added input field but it is not wroking

````
```
 cellView.model.addPort({ markup: '<foreignObject x="0" y="-150" height="300" width="300"  >  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="bg-red"> <div class="header"> <span> Activate </span> <div> <span>starteNode</span> <img src="icons/cube.png" /> </div></div> <div class="cell-content" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <p class="cell__title"> Node Intent </p>  <div class="input__label"> Training Data </div> <input type="text" value="activate" />          <text contentEditable="true">foo</text>  <div class="input__label">Answers</div> <input type="text" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" value="Did You mean debit" > </input> </div> <div class="connectors">  <div class="connectors__title"> Connectors </div> </div> </div></foreignObject>' });
```
````

can anyone why the input feild is not working inside my forgein object (user are not able to edit the input element)

Comment: what does not working mean? Can you create a [mcve] because we can't run that one line on its own.

Comment: @RobertLongson working means user are not able to make changes in input feild

Comment: Try event.stopPropagation(); on specific input  click event on initial @RajRana